# How to show or hide status bar on different screens in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and trying to create some app in which I want to show or hide status bar  on different screens.In main screen I don't want to show status bar for that I have set its property `hidden={true}` but on doing  this its also not visible on other screens how can I make it visible on other screens.

In `Onboard` and `Home` and screen I want to show status bar and in `Login` and `Register` screen I don't wanna show status bar.

Below is my code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Onboard from './components/Onboard';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Home from './components/Home';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {

return (
  <NavigationContainer>
   <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
    <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen
       name="Onboard"
       component={Onboard}
       options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Login"
      component={Login}
      options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Register"
      component={Register} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Home} 
      options={{ 
        headerLeft: null,
        headerTintColor:'white',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#e57373',
          elevation:0,
          shadowOpacity:0
       } }}/>  
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Someone let me know how can I achieve desired results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to put StatusBar... in every screen, you can also use `useFocusEffect` hook of react-navigation. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

It is cleaner and easy to read.

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

```js
useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
  // This will run when screen is `focused` or mounted.
  StatusBar.setHidden(true);

  // This will run when screen is `blured` or unmounted.
  return () => {
    StatusBar.setHidden(false);
  }
}, []));
```

Comment: Is there any way to change color of status bar for different screens.

Comment: You can use the methods of StatusBar to change the style https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#setbarstyle

Comment: when I am trying your solution I am getting this error ` [TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _react.useFocusEffect)...')]`.

Comment: @Digvijay useFocusEffect should be imported from react navigation, not react. `import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';`

Comment: Yeah now it's working fine I did wrong import. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount() {
   StatusBar.setHidden(false);
}
```

Add this code to every page's class. Write **true** or **false** to show and hide.

Comment: I am using functional component so do I need to use  `useEffect()` hook instead of `componentDidMMount()` ?